# Simple ReactJS Pagination

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactJS and I'm making simple To-do app(Without mongoDB),I already implemented:Add,Delete,Edit functionalities.Now I want to add simple pagination to it.
For example:if there are 5 items on page create new page and transfer 6th element on the second page and etc..
Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use any pagination npm package, for example
https://reactjsexample.com/reactjs-component-for-easy-pagination/
Select the source for your data and pagination data from your state for example.